# How to determine suitable image size for device from list of available sizes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, responsive-design, screen-resolution

For an item, I have images available of following sizes:

```
[ { "h": 1004, "w": 768 }, { "h": 748, "w": 1024 }, { "h": 460, "w": 320 }, { "h": 920, "w": 640 }, { "h": 300, "w": 480 }, { "h": 600, "w": 960 }, { "h": 720, "w": 1280 } ]
```

How can I write a function in JavaScript/AngularJS to return the closest appropriate size based on current device, resolution and orientation?

Comment: Why not just use media queries?

Comment: I need this functionality for image tiles layout and images will be queried form server based on determined size at run-time.

Comment: You should start by posting more code, your question is not clear on what your needs are and we now are left with guessing.

Comment: I didn't start coding yet. The scenario is I have to list items in tile/grid layout. For a single item, API returns image urls for all above mentioned sizes. How do I know, which url to use to load image from for a particular item?

Comment: We are not here to code for you, if you have a specific code issue SO is the place to ask, I would recommend researching it first, give it your best shot and if you still need help, re-post the question with relevant code.

Comment: Right, I'll research. Maybe somebody find my question valid and answer it in a way that'll help me.

Comment: Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using media queries: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/88z7u4kf/

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/");
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/800/800/");
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/600/");
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/");
    }
}
```

Comment: How will I deal with dynamic image urls, coming in APIs.

Comment: I don't know, you did not specify that in your question.